# Unable to authenticate with Twitter using Twitter4j on Android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

So, I'm getting a 'No authentication challenges found' error when trying to authenticate through Twitter. And before you ask, yes, I've googled the issue; there were only three pages of results, and none of them seemed to help. It also doesn't help matters that all GitHub projects using Twitter4j are out of date, as are all the tutorials and guides I managed to find...

Anyway, here's the relevant code I've got:

```
class TwitterGetAccessTokenTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String userName) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, ActivityToLaunch.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        Twitter twitter = TwitterUtil.getInstance().getTwitter();
        RequestToken requestToken = TwitterUtil.getInstance().getRequestToken();

        try {
            AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, ConstantValues.URL_PARAMETER_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);

            long userId = accessToken.getUserId();

            return twitter.showUser(userId).getName();
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

That code is run from an onClick event, and should be fairly easy to follow: on button click, execute a new background task. In that task, we get a request token (which I know to be valid, as I'm logging them out). We then try to swap that request token for an access token, and that's what throws the error. Here's the stack trace:

```
11-21 16:41:37.152: W/System.err(3534): No authentication challenges found
11-21 16:41:37.152: W/System.err(3534): Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
11-21 16:41:37.152: W/System.err(3534):     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=bb0a5eb5 or
11-21 16:41:37.152: W/System.err(3534):     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=324c40aa
11-21 16:41:37.152: W/System.err(3534): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[bb0a5eb5-324c40aa 5147af80-173bd05c], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.5}
11-21 16:41:37.152: W/System.err(3534):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:177)
11-21 16:41:37.152: W/System.err(3534):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
11-21 16:41:37.152: W/System.err(3534):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:89)
11-21 16:41:37.152: W/System.err(3534):     at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1911)
11-21 16:41:37.152: W/System.err(3534):     at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.showUser(TwitterImpl.java:852)
11-21 16:41:37.152: W/System.err(3534):     at com.myapp.CurrentActivity.TwitterActivity$TwitterGetAccessTokenTask.doInBackground(TwitterActivity.java:90)
11-21 16:41:37.152: W/System.err(3534):     at com.myapp.CurrentActivity.TwitterActivity$TwitterGetAccessTokenTask.doInBackground(TwitterActivity.java:1)
11-21 16:41:37.152: W/System.err(3534):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-21 16:41:37.152: W/System.err(3534):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-21 16:41:37.152: W/System.err(3534):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-21 16:41:37.152: W/System.err(3534):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-21 16:41:37.152: W/System.err(3534):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-21 16:41:37.152: W/System.err(3534):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-21 16:41:37.152: W/System.err(3534):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-21 16:41:37.152: W/System.err(3534): Caused by: java.io.IOException: No authentication challenges found
11-21 16:41:37.160: W/System.err(3534):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getAuthorizationCredentials(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:427)
11-21 16:41:37.160: W/System.err(3534):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processAuthHeader(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
11-21 16:41:37.160: W/System.err(3534):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:356)
11-21 16:41:37.160: W/System.err(3534):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)
11-21 16:41:37.160: W/System.err(3534):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:486)
11-21 16:41:37.160: W/System.err(3534):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:134)
11-21 16:41:37.160: W/System.err(3534):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpResponseImpl.<init>(HttpResponseImpl.java:34)
11-21 16:41:37.160: W/System.err(3534):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:141)
11-21 16:41:37.160: W/System.err(3534):     ... 13 more
```

My question, then, is short and sweet: How do I properly authenticate through Twitter, using Twitter4j version 3.0.5? What am I doing wrong that is causing this error? Any and all help is very much appreciated!

**Edit:** It might be helpful of me to include the code for the TwitterUtil class that I'm using:

```
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.auth.RequestToken;
import twitter4j.conf.Configuration;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

public final class TwitterUtil {

    private RequestToken requestToken = null;
    private TwitterFactory twitterFactory = null;
    private Twitter twitter;

    public TwitterUtil() {
        ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(ConstantValues.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
        configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(ConstantValues.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        Configuration configuration = configurationBuilder.build();
        twitterFactory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
        twitter = twitterFactory.getInstance();
    }

    public TwitterFactory getTwitterFactory()
    {
        return twitterFactory;
    }

    public void setTwitterFactory(AccessToken accessToken)
    {
        twitter = twitterFactory.getInstance(accessToken);
    }

    public Twitter getTwitter()
    {
        return twitter;
    }
    public RequestToken getRequestToken() {
        if (requestToken == null) {
            try {
                requestToken = twitterFactory.getInstance().getOAuthRequestToken(ConstantValues.TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return requestToken;
    }

    static TwitterUtil instance = new TwitterUtil();

    public static TwitterUtil getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void reset() {
        instance = new TwitterUtil();
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:** Note that the error in the stack trace is thrown from the call to getOAUthAccessToken, i.e. `AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, ConstantValues.URL_PARAMETER_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);`

Comment: Just realised I've edited this before, but it was rolled back. If you are minded to roll back again, please ping me, so I can involve a moderator. Thank you @Capitrium.

Comment: @halfer I am minded to roll back again; the edits you've made are, for the most part, technically incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The purpose of the edit is to remove [urgent begging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495), which is obviously not appreciated by volunteers (anywhere on the web, but here explicitly also). I have also removed some noise and some excessive formatting, but otherwise I cannot see how my edits are incorrect. Can you elucidate on what is now wrong in the question?

Comment: Most of the "noise and excessive formatting" changes are unnecessary and/or incorrect: not being able to start sentences with a conjunction is actually a myth, with both Garner’s Modern American Usage and Fowler’s Modern English Usage calling this belief a superstition; your addition of whitespace after the last sentence in the first paragraph is incorrect; your removal of an ellipsis, indicating an omission of text by the author, seems unfounded; finally, capitalization of the first word in a sentence following a colon is only technically necessary if more than one sentence follows the colon.

Comment: The removal of the begging was the primary intention, and the reduction of lengthy emboldening does increase readability. I'll happily give way on the other items, which would have been too minor on their own to justify edits. Thanks for the commentary, most interesting!

Comment: I was intrigued by your point about the "so" prefix, so I looked it up. I've always thought of this as a redundant _contextualiser_, but it turns out it is also a _discourse marker_. The first purpose is to denote material that follows from an unspoken context, or that the first couple of sentences is the setting of that context; the second is a pre-announcement, rather like clearing one's throat to make room for a speech. Myself, I don't like it, [and neither do these folks](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43273/sentences-beginning-with-so). However...

Comment: ... as engineers I think we seek out redundancy, and we eliminate it to obtain simplicity, but perhaps we (I) should be careful, since speaking and writing and not merely technical. Interestingly, [here are](http://www.businessinsider.com/heres-why-everyone-is-starting-sentences-with-the-word-so-2014-5?r=US&IR=T&IR=T) some [perspectives](http://www.npr.org/2015/09/03/432732859/so-whats-the-big-deal-with-starting-a-sentence-with-so) that do not condemn it - and apparently this usage is not new either. [Plenty more](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=starting+sentences+with+so) here too!

Answer (score 1):

Eventually managed to figure this one out on my own. The key was to split out getting a request token into it's own AsyncTask, like so:

```
class TwitterGetRequestTokenTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, RequestToken> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(RequestToken requestToken) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL()));
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected RequestToken doInBackground(String... params) {
        return TwitterUtil.getInstance().getRequestToken();
    }
}
```

The code in the onPostExecute() method brings up the Twitter authentication page where the user allows your app to access their account. After this, put the following line in your manifest file for whichever activity you want the Twitter web page to redirect back to after authenticating (note that it does not have to be the same activity which launched the intent!):

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<!-- The following line should match your callback url; mine is oauth://com.example.myapp -->
<data android:scheme="oauth" android:host="com.example.myapp" />
```

Finally, put the following code in the activity that will handle the actual generation of the access token and any subsequent storage/use of that data:

```
class TwitterGetAccessTokenTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        // The user's name is now in 's', so you can do stuff with it
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String verifier = params[0];

        Twitter twitter = TwitterUtil.getInstance().getTwitter();
        RequestToken requestToken = TwitterUtil.getInstance().getRequestToken();

        try {
            AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
            // You can store the access token data now however you'd like
            // You can also use it to get data from the user's Twitter account
            long userId = accessToken.getUserId();
            return twitter.showUser(userId).getName();
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

I think that covers everything you need to get twitter4j authentication working... hopefully this helps someone out!

Comment: Calling TwitterGetRequestTokenTask i will go to twitters authentification page and after I'm back to my app (that's great!). But then I want to post some message with account that user logged in. I'm looking at your example and cant figure out what is verifier on TwitterGetAccessTokenTask and where could i get it?

Comment: @Ragaisis Twitter sends back a URI which you can grab in the activity that launches when you return to your app:
`Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
if(uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(ConstantValues.TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
    String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(ConstantValues.URL_PARAMETER_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);
    new TwitterGetAccessTokenTask().execute(verifier);
}`

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I've posted my code as [a library on GitHub](https://github.com/Capitrium/TwitterAuth) that you should be able to use in any Android project (currently only tested on Android 4.0+)

Comment: After a successful authorization, It redirects me back to the app but params[0] returns null. Could you please suggest me a way to get verifier for requesting access token?